# How to assign users to a group

Tags: 7, users

How do I assign users to a group in Drupal 7? Basically I wanted to have following groups in my website.

1. Administrators
2. Content Writer and Publisher
3. Registered users

I wanted to assign all of the newly registered users to "Registered users" group automatically and I as a member of administrator should be able to assign some trusted users into "Content Writer and Publisher" group.

Each of these groups will have different-2 permissions as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a permission point of view, (instead of groups) these are called "roles" in Drupal. (From a content-user-access point of view there is the Organic groups module, but that's another story.)

You can administer roles at admin/people/permissions/roles. You can mass assign users to roles at admin/people (Update options - Add a role to selected users).

All registered users automatically have a role called "authenticated user", so there is no need to duplicate that functionality.

For more info check out "Managing access control with permissions and user roles" at 
https://drupal.org/node/22275

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Registration Role](https://drupal.org/project/registration_role):

From the module's project page:

> Registration role lets an administrator select a role to automatically assign to new users. The selected role will be assigned to new registrants.

It assigns a selected role on signup of a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I use - [Role field](https://drupal.org/project/role_field), [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules). Create field role and assign this role from Rules module.